# How to move back and forth in same Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I am having problem in moving back and forward on same activity. Is it possiable to do that?

I am using GCM to create Notification, on Receving notification I am using WakefulBroadcastReceiver to Invoke a Activity. My requirement is like After receiveing second notification my Activity starts and a New screen with Current Data shows on screen. When I click back button the screen on which first notification was displayed able to see it. Is it possiable for me to go back to the second notification screen.
I have one Activity but different Instances.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

and GCMNotificationIntentService has the following activity.

```
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, GcmHomeActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

This is the Intent which invoking my activity which shows the Notification Message

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    // Intent Message sent from Broadcast Receiver
    String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("msg");
    msgET = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        msgET.setText(str);
```

}

Comment: Since they are two different activities, loaded through through two different notifications (as opposed to Activity A loading into Activity B), I don't think you can just "go back." But you should be able to call `finishActivity()` and it should close the current one and the previous one should resurface since it's a stack of activities.

Comment: In general, the default behaviour is what you want, so it should already work like this. Please post your manifest, maybe you are doing something strange that is causing this problem.

Comment: As I understand your question, the app receives a GCM message and displays it in an instance of `GcmHomeActivity`.  A second GCM message is received, which causes instance #1 of `GcmHomeActivity` to go into the background and a second instance of `GcmHomeActivity` is created and displayed.  You press the Back button, which pops activity instance #2 and displayed instance #1.  You are asking if it is possible to return to instance #2. It is not possible in this case because Back destroys the activity when it pops it. Instead of Back, maybe the "recent tasks" screen can be used to switch between

Comment: Thankyou for the reply, #qbix  as said  you correct, it is the behavior i want , can you please elaborate how to achieve this recent task

Comment: Siva: I wasn't notified when you replied to my comment because you used # instead of @ with my user name.  The "recent tasks" or "overview" screen is [described here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/recents.html).  There were capabilities added in API 21 that might be helpful.  Of course, that isn't a solution for pre-Lollipop devices.

Comment: @qbix, thankyou for the information,  but i have Jellybean devices also to be used so any other way is there to achieve this for pre-5.0 devices,  i have thought much but can't able to further.